# Changing static text in dialog box at runtime

Tags: c++, mfc

I have created a dialog box and linked it to the menu item. In this case the menu item is *Help -> Statistics*. It all works. So when I run the program, click on the menu *Help*, then *Statistics*, a dialog box pops up.

I also have a static text box in the dialog box. How do you change the text of this static text box at runtime?

P.S: Though I have a dialog box up and running, I do not have the handle for the dialog box. If any of your solutions involve knowing the handle to the dialog box, please tell me how to retrieve it. Thanks.

EDIT:

```
class CStatisticsDlg : public CDialogEx
{
public:
        CStatisticsDlg();

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_STATISTICS };

protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

// Implementation
protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
};

CStatisticsDlg::CStatisticsDlg() : CDialogEx(CStatisticsDlg::IDD)
{
}

void CStatisticsDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CStatisticsDlg, CDialogEx)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Comment: It could be helpful if you provided the code you are using for the dialog.

Comment: just added the code that is responsible for creating the dialog box.

Answer (score 8):

1. In Class Wizard, create a CString  member variable for the label. Note: by default, labels don't have a custom id so you have to give it one like IDC_MY_LABEL.
2. Somewhere before showing the dialog call `m_strMyLabel.SetWindowText("blah");`

If you need to do it while the dialog is open you have to call `UpdateData(FALSE)`

Edit: if you don't want to create a member variable you can
**corrected - typing from memory....

```
// Find the label
// if called from within CStatusDlg class
CWnd *label = GetDlgItem(IDC_MY_LABEL);
label->SetWindowText("blah");

// If called from elsewhere
CStatusDlg dlg.....  // create the dialog
CWnd *label = dlg.GetDlgItem(IDC_MY_LABEL);
label->SetWindowText("blah");
```

Comment: thx for the reply. How would you do this programtically(i.e. without the class wizard)?